# How many singular vectors do we need to calculate for SVD?

Tags: hyperparameter-optimization, hyper-parameters, feature-selection, singular-value-decomposition

In the geometrical interpretation of SVD, the data points that we have need to be imagined as points in high dimensional space (say $d$-dimensional space). But we need to find a hyperplane in $k-$dimensional subspace that best fits the given data points

> To gain insight into the SVD, treat the rows of an $n \times d$ matrix $A$ as $n$ points in a $d$-dimensional space and consider the problem of finding the best **$k$-dimensional** subspace with respect to the set of points.

My doubt here is about the uniqueness of $k$. Can we do decomposition for any $k \le d$ or for only certain values of $k$ or only for an unique $k$?

---

The paragraph is taken from the material on Singular Value Decomposition available [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Evenkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-4.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The number of singular vectors we need to find during SVD is not unique. The possible values for k are from 1 to $r$. Here, $r$ is the rank of matrix $A$, on which we are performing decomposition.

The same pdf says that

> First, in many applications, the data matrix $A$ is close to a matrix of
> low rank and it is useful to find a low rank matrix which is a good
> approximation to the data matrix .  We will show that from the singular
> value decomposition of $A$, we can get the matrix $B$ of rank $k$ which best
> approximates $A$; **in fact we can do this for every $k$**.  Also, singular
> value decomposition is defined for all matrices (rectangular or
> square)unlike the more commonly used spectral decomposition in Linear
> Algebra.

So, the value of $k$ is up to the designer. If the designer selects the value of $k$ smaller than the rank $r$ of the matrix $A$, then it is called as [truncated SVD](http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/na/m/86/36/NA-M-86-36.pdf).